# Can graphs have a serialized canonical form for the purpose of very fast graph structure look-up (subgraph isomorphism)?

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, graph-isomorphism, search, subgraphs

Let suppose we order the nodes first by degree (in + out), to get a list of node structures:

```
Node:
   labels: []   # lexicographic ordered
   out_arrows: []  # ordered by ordering of the nodes
   in_arrows: []   # ordered by ordering of the nodes
```

Then how should we order the nodes that have equal degree?  Or am I approaching this the wrong way?  My end goal is to have O(Q) to O(log N) graph lookup where N is the size of my library and Q is the size of a much smaller query graph.  Not only that but once you convert the serialized data to a hashable type such as a string, then you can perform the search using a standard data structure (dictionary or map).

What is some work done in this area, i.e. have people already thought of this standard form serialization and search method?

---

Note that the *key* graphs my library will hold are relatively small (5-50) nodes, but their may be a million of them in the library.  So it's not advised to perform a usual subgraph isomorphism search of the whole library say using Ullmann's algorithm, because for the most part, the graph is disconnected.

Comment: What do you mean by "should"?  You can do it any way you want.  Are you asking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization?

Comment: @D.W. I mean graph-to-string canonization.  Labels will need to match exactly.  But any two label-matched, isomorphic graphs will have the same resulting string, so therefore you can key them into a dictionary (Python) or map (C++/STL)

Comment: Check out [Nauty](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/)

Comment: @PålGD that's nice, but I'm going to be implementing a solution in Python.   I will post the code of SerializedObject / Arrow / Label, mostly to explain more of what I mean.  I think it's an elegant solution to my library search problems.  Here is my project repository: https://github.com/enjoysmath/abstract-spacecraft  What's neat about this solution is that dictionary lookup in python is incredibly fast relative to for-loops in Python, so this solution shouldn't be much slower than an equivalent C++ version.  Now my project can be entirely Python-based without having to put in a C++ backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph canonization is well-studied, and there are sophisticated algorithms for it; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization.  The standard answer is to use existing, well-tuned software, such as Nauty, rather than trying to invent your own.

How to implement in Python is out of scope of this site (but I would investigate API bindings or running it on the command line).

See also [Graph isomorphism problem for labeled graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28714/755).